# Intersections of finitely generated field extensions are finite?

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory

I was reading the following post at MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21086/when-are-intersections-of-finitely-generated-field-extensions-finitely-generated/21093

I can't comment there, and I feel this is a lower level question, so I want to ask for clarification here.

In the second proof near the end in the answer given, the author says

> Since algebraic independence is of finite character, we may assume that $B$ is finite. Since $L'(B)/K(B)$ is algebraic, we have...

It must be obvious, but why is $L'(B)/K(B)$ algebraic? (I'll try to copy the post over here to make this more self-contained in the mean time.)

Comment: Because $L'/K$ is algebraic.

Comment: Missed that part, I feel dumb. Thanks...